# Remove inline styles when clicking on button

Tags: javascript

The following happens to me:

I have made a slider with the next and previous arrows that works correctly. The case is that I have a button called "see all" in which when I press it, it puts a display none to the previous and next arrows and shows everything that is in the slider (that is to say, when I press the button, it shows everything and "deactivates" the slider).

The problem is that when you press the button again to stop displaying everything and return to "slider mode", the previous and next buttons do not go through the slider.

The slider is putting the active class and removing it to show what is inside. But once I have used the button of "see all" it is added in line a "display: none" and although I give to the arrows of previous or following and the class active is put correctly it remains the style="display:none;" inline in the html and it stops working.

The code of the button that shows everything:

```
var btnMore = document.querySelector(".btn-panes");
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("#slider .box-panes");
var aLeft = document.querySelector("#slider .left");
var aRight = document.querySelector("#slider .right");
var btnMoreActivated = false;

btnMore.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!btnMoreActivated){
        for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++ ){
            document.querySelector("#slider").style.flexWrap = "wrap";
            boxes[i].style.display = "flex";
            aLeft.classList.add("ocultar");
            aRight.classList.add("ocultar");
        }
        btnMoreActivated = true;
    } else {
        for(var i=1; i<boxes.length; i++ ){
            boxes[i].style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector("#slider").style.flexFlow = "nowrap";
            aLeft.classList.remove("ocultar");
            aRight.classList.remove("ocultar");
        }
        btnMoreActivated = false;
    }
});
```

The slider code (it works) but just to show you what it does in case you need to add something to fix the problem:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#slider .box-panes');
const itemCount = items.length;
const nextItem = document.querySelectorAll('.right img');
const previousItem = document.querySelectorAll('.left img');
var count = 0;


function shorHide(){
  switch (key) {
    case value:
      
      break;
  
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function showNextItem() {
  items[count].classList.remove('active');

  if(count < itemCount - 1) {
    count++;
  } else {
    count = 0;
  }
  items[count].classList.add('active');
}

function showPreviousItem() {
  items[count].classList.remove('active');
  if(count > 0) {
    count--;
  } else {
    count = itemCount - 1;
  }
  items[count].classList.add('active');
}

function keyPress(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  
  if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    showPreviousItem();
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    showNextItem();
  }
}


nextItem[0].addEventListener('click', showNextItem);
previousItem[0].addEventListener('click', showPreviousItem);
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
```

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the inline style directly? `aLeft.style.display = '...'` (I don't know what display value they have originally, if they are absolutely positioned anyway, then `block` should do no harm.)

Answer (score 0):

This is because inline styles are the most [specific type of style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to add and therefore the most difficult to override. **The simplest solution is to not use inline styles and instead use a class that can be added or removed as needed.**

Here's a simple example that you can use to replace: `boxes[i].style.display = "none";`

```js
// Get the elements that need to be hidden/shown into a collection
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav");

document.getElementById("hide").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  // Loop over the collection
  btns.forEach(function(el){
    el.classList.add("hidden"); // Apply the hidden class
  });
});

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  btns.forEach(function(el){
    el.classList.remove("hidden");  // Remove the class
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<button id="hide">Hide Buttons</button>
<button id="show">Show Buttons</button>

<button class="nav">&lt;&lt;</button> <button class="nav">&gt;&gt;</button>
```